# How can I send a variable to a script for data to be viewed? (xcode)

Tags: xcode

So i have recently been diving into the world of apps and using xcode to build them, most apps so far have been simple and quite painless to build... apart from one.

My problem is i have built a questionnaire app which has a user enter information in  a UItextfiled which then is forwarded to a UIlabel... all this works fine however the client now wants the data to be sent to an online script so information can be view at a later date.
Im not really sure where to start... how can i get each different variable communicating with the online script so the data is sent? I know i need to add the URL so the app can connect with the script but not sure where to start.

Any help would be grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by doing some studying up on RESTful web APIs and how to communicate with them from an iOS app. There are plenty of options. A couple of the more popular repos out there that would help with this are AFNetworking and RestKit.